# Format of several x inputs for training multi input functional keras model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, dataformat

So I am currently trying to understand what formats a multi input keras model expect and don´t understand how to feed in several ones.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow as tf

first_input = Input(2)
second_input = Input(2)
concat_layer= Concatenate()([first_input, second_input ])
hidden= Dense(2, activation="relu")(concat_layer)
output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(hidden)
model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=output)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'], optimizer='adam')

# I managed to get the format for prediction and single training data correct
# this works
inp = [np.array([[0,2]]), np.array([[0,2]])]
model.predict(inp)
model.fit(inp,np.array([42]), epochs=3, )

# I don´t get why this isn´t working
# this doesn´t work
model.fit(np.array([inp,inp]),np.array([42, 43]), epochs=3, )´
```

Having read the keras doc of the fit function I really don´t understand why my version isn´t working:

*x : Vector, matrix, or array of training data (or list if the model has multiple inputs). If all inputs in the model are named, you can also pass a list mapping input names to data. x can be NULL (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).*

Because I am literally giving it an array of lists.

The last code line results in following error:

*ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 2, 1, 2) dtype=int64>]*

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the model

```
model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=output)
```

This means that the inputs are expected to be a list of 2 tensors with shapes (2,) and one output with shape (1,) (as defined by the last Dense layer).

So, when you use as arguments:

```
inp = [np.array([[0,2]]), np.array([[0,2]])]
```

This is a list with 2 arrays of shape (1, 2)

And

```
np.array([42])
```

which is an array with shape (1)

This matches your model definition. [Actually the output should have a shape of (1, 1)]

The line

```
model.fit(np.array([inp,inp]),np.array([42, 43]))
```

Is trying to feed an a list of lists of arrays with an overall shape of [2, 2, 1, 2] and a target with shape [2]. This doesn't match the model definition.

Since it is easy to get this wrong, i tend to like to build the arguments to the .fit or predict call first and then explicitly print their shapes...

e.g.

```
x_train = [a, b] # where a and b are np.arrays
print([x.shape for x in x_train])
```

For instance try:

```
x_first = np.random.rand(8, 2) # batch_size 8, feature_size 2
x_second = np.random.rand(8, 2)
x_train = [a, b]

y_true = np.random.rand(8)

model.fit(x_train, y_true)
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply but how would a correctly formatted input look now exactly?

Comment: I am currently trying to really understand tensor shapes and you wrote that the target shape of "np.array([42, 43])" was (1,2) but isn´t it actually just (2) or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct: np.array([42, 43]) is a shape of (2,), my mistake.

Comment: @SegmentationFaultLover added an invocation example using random values.